# Series of actions in one script, successively

Tags: autohotkey

AutoHotKey. 
Leraning how to make a series of actions, with strings, files, variables etc. From 1 to 101 of them. Files in one folder or folders in one folder, strings from high, variables in one script. By more simple and classical methods.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're going to need to put a lot more effort into your question if you want help here. I read *AutoHotKey. some vague words, more vague words*. If you want help, clearly state what you're trying to do, the problem you're having doing so, include what you've done so far that isn't working for you, and *ask a specific question*. We're not mind readers, and we're not a code writing service where you post some vague description of your needs and someone churns out code for you. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/helpl/how-to-ask) for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do multiple similar actions it's almost always a good idea to use some form of loop.
Arrays can also help a lot.

Here's a file/folder loop:

```
Loop Files, C:\*.exe, R  ; get all .exe files that are on C:\ and subfolders of it
{
    MsgBox, Full path of the current file: %A_LoopFileFullPath%
    If (A_LoopFileName = "virus.exe") {
        MsgBox, A file called virus.exe was found.
    }
}
```

Here's a normal loop:

```
Loop, 101 ;run the following code 101 times
{
    MsgBox, This is iteration number %A_Index%
    If (A_Index = 10)
        MsgBox, Nice! You made it through 10 iterations!
}
```

...

```
Loop, 101 ;run the following code 101 times
{
    If (A_Index >= 10 && A_Index < 20)
        MsgBox, This is iteration number %A_Index%. (10-20)
    If (A_Index >= 37 && A_Index < 71)
    {
        MsgBox, This is iteration number %A_Index%. (37-71)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. My OS 32-bit and AHK 32-bit version. Is it possible to say exactly,  A_Index a 64-bit integer or 32-bit for it?

Comment: Well, if loop is empty it do nothing and counting A_Index.

Comment: How make this code If (A_Index = 10) for sequence 10 to 20, 37 to 71, etc?

Comment: A_Index is probably an 8 byte integer, also known as "long". This is should be more than enough to count through decades. And you are right, if the loop is "empty" it will do nothing but counting up A_Index. I'll add some more code for your last concern.